# SQL Select entries where none of the entities have a value in a particular column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table of data which has students and their subject results in it. The students will appear multiple times, once for each subject they have a result for.

```
**tableID,studentID,lastName,firstName,subject,grade**
1,1a,Student1,Name1,English,A
2,1a,Student1,Name1,Maths,A
3,1a,Student1,Name1,Science,A
4,2a,Student2,Name2,English,A
5,2a,Student2,Name2,Maths,B
6,2a,Student2,Name2,Science,A
7,3a,Student3,Name3,English,A
8,3a,Student3,Name3,Maths,A
```

---

Using Microsoft Access SQL, how can I select only the students who have received an A for all of their subjects? E.g. In the above table, I only want to select all instances of Student1 and Student3, I don't want Student2 as they have not received all A's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the results I want by using a sub-query:

```
SELECT studentID, lastName, firstName
FROM table
WHERE grade = "A"
AND studentID NOT IN (SELECT studentID FROM table WHERE grade <> "A" GROUP BY studentID)
GROUP BY studentID, lastName, firstName
```

This seems to exclude all students who received a result other than an A.

Answer (score 1):

Get all students with grade A except students with any other grade

```
SELECT 
     studentID,lastName,firstName
FROM
(SELECT 
     studentID,lastName,firstName
FROM
    result
WHERE
    grade = 'A'
GROUP BY
    studentID,lastName,firstName) GradeA
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT 
     studentID,lastName,firstName
FROM
    result
WHERE
    grade <> 'A'
GROUP BY
    studentID,lastName,firstName) GradeOther
    ON GradeA.studentId = GradeOther.StudentID AND GradeA.LAstName = GradeOther.LastName AND GradeA.FirstName = GradeOther.FirstName
WHERE 
    GradeOther.StudentID IS NULL
```

Comment: This did not work, there was an issue with the "EXCEPT" keyword (MS Access does not appear to support this, I kept getting a syntax error about a missing operator).

However, this did get me thinking on the right track to solve it - using a sub query.

Comment: @Tristan Modified the answer to not use EXCEPT

Answer (score 0):

One way is using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
select StudentId
from t
group by StudentId
having max(grade) = min(grade) and max(grade) = 'A';
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this still showed entries from students who received a B or other grades as well.

Comment: @Tristan . . . I cannot see how this query would return students who have a grade other than 'A'.  That doesn't seem possible.

Comment: So, this is the SQL I used:


`SELECT studentID, grade
FROM table
GROUP BY studenID, grade
HAVING MAX(grade) = MIN(grade) AND MAX(grade) = "A";`

The result was a list of ID's with the grades showing as all A's. However when I look at the original data for some of those students, I can see that the query simply omitted the subjects where the student did not get an A.

Comment: @Tristan . . . If the students have different grades, then the `min()` and `max()` would not be equal to each other.